# torsion and torsion-free groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I have the following statement:
Every finitely-generated abelian group $G$ is isomorphic to $T\bigoplus F$, where T and F are torsion and free groups.

As an example is given that all abelian groups of order 72 are of this type.

I take all group of order 8: $\mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\bigoplus\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\bigoplus\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\bigoplus\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$

And all groups of order 9: $\mathbb{Z}/9\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}\bigoplus\mathbb{Z}/3$

but the conclusion is missing.. all groups are torsion groups as finite what about the free part?

Comment: That is not really an example of the statement you've written down. Neither of those groups are free. The torsion subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_8$ is itself.

Comment: ah yes you are right I interpreted it wrong... But why should not be free this groups? I found a definition for a group to be free that is: F is free if it is an abelian group with a basis and each element can be written uniquely as linear combination with integer coefficients. Is it a wrong definition?

Comment: Your definition is correct. I claim it doesn't hold in any group with torsion in it (exercise).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $T$ is torsion, then $T\simeq \{0\}\oplus T$, so the free part is the trivial group. In fact in your definition of free group you have to specify that you want nonzero element to be unique $\mathbb Z$-linear combinations of the basis, and such a condition holds in the trivial group, since it is just the empty condition.